# Start Highchart xAxis value from start and end of line

Tags: highcharts

I want to start Xaxis value from start and end of line, I just don't want that little space, [image]

http: //jsfiddle.net/hdmrr5m7/1/

is there any option in highcahrt which can be used to remove those extra spaces ?

Comment: In Highcharts you have options on padding axis. In your case you are looking to add minPadding: 0.0 to your X-axis  xAxis: {
            startOnTick: false,
            minPadding: 0.0
        },

Comment: min/max padding will do nothing for a categorized axis.  Option 1: use date time instead of categories. Option 2 - search SO for the multitude of other questions on this subject.